# How to Create EAR file in RAD 7.5

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, websphere, rad, ear

I have checked out a dynamic web project from a CVS repository. But, there was no EAR file to check in. Now how can I create an EAR file for the project to deploy in WAS 6?

Also can I run my project in RAD without creating an .ear file? I am a newbie to Java EE projects.

Comment: The documentation for creating an EAR and adding a module (WAR) is in the Infocenter [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.jee5.doc/topics/tcreateentappproj.html). I believe you can run a WAR on WAS 6  without an EAR file but it has been a while since I worked with that version. Use the _Run As... Run on server_ menu to try.

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to export an EAR, you can add a new **Enterprise Application project** ( New > Enterprise Application project) and select your Web project as a **Java EE module dependency**.

This way you can export an EAR file that will contain a WAR file built from your Web project.

Comment: Thanks for your response.But how to configure RAD so that I can test and debug my application from within the RAD workbench.

Comment: The following [redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247672.html) should be useful to you to learn more about developing with RAD.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the wizard for creating a new enterprise application (File->New), one of the options is to add an existing web project in your workspace into the application as you create it. You can then export the enterprise application as an EAR file ready to deploy into WebSphere Application Server or, if you have the test environment set up, you can just drag-and-drop it onto the server in the Servers view. To test your web application, right-click it and choose Run->Run on Server.

Comment: Thanks for your response.But how to configure RAD so that I can test and debug my application from within the RAD workbench.

Comment: The redbook mentioned by trikelef should get you going there.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing as project instead of EAR files